# How to use Apache as proxy for Angular/Spring-Boot to prevent CORS-scenario?

Tags: angular, spring, apache, proxy

I have a small Angular app running along with a Spring-Boot-Backend (both running on localhost with different ports) and so far had it configured that I could serve/run both from CLI/IDE and it would work well but I had to use the

```
@CrossOrigin{...}
```

annotation on my Spring-Controller.

How can I use an Apache as proxy to eliminate the CORS-scenario in the first place?
(I have pretty limited experience in this area; mostly did some rewrite-rules in the past.)

From what I read so far, the proxy-module is already integrated into Apache 2.4 but I am somewhat lost how to use it for my scenario.

I hope this question is not too unspecific and I'm thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you are using them in a dev environment (localhost). In this case, you can use the built-in proxy of Angular CLI (which is webpack dev): https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

> Create a file proxy.conf.json in your project's src/ folder.
>   Add the following content to the new proxy file (change the port 3000 to the one of your spring boot app):

```js
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

> In the CLI configuration file, angular.json, add the proxyConfig option to the serve target:

```js
...
"architect": {
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "your-application-name:build",
      "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
...
```

> To run the dev server with this proxy configuration, call `ng serve`.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your time! I did what you proposed (changed "/api" to "/" though) but I still get CORS-errors. Situation: I do some request to the Spring-Boot-embedded-Tomcat via Angular's httpClient like this.httpClient.get("http://localhost:8080/myStuff") and am informed that CORS-headers are missing.

Comment: You must not change to "/" because the proxy should know how when to serve the static files, and when to proxy the request. And do not call your url like `localhost:8080` but directly: `this.httpClient.get('/myStuff')`. You should add `/myStuff` in the proxy.conf. That's why it is recommended to have something like `/api` to all the paths of the your API Spring boot like `/api/myStuff`, that way, you only need to have proxy only `/api`.